# Kitchen vent accessed for use on other side of a wall?

Tags: walls, kitchens, vent, interior

We are thinking about buying an apartment and creating a small interior room in the living room.

One of the walls in the living room shares a wall with the kitchen. This shared wall in the kitchen has a vent that sucks air out of the room.

Is it possible to use this kitchen vent in the shared wall to also vent the small room we want to create on the other side of the wall? Do vents work like this and do you think a co-op board would allow such a modification?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a vent that is driven by a fan at the END of the vent, or a range hood at the START of the vent?

The range hood will push the air into your other room, but the fan will pull air from both rooms. The fan would work but it will reduce its efficiency due to its power being split across the two rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Vents dont work that way. Smells from the kitchen will go to the other room.

It may work if there is a reasonable fan towards the exterior end of the vent. But if the fan fails you are back to the above situation.  I  wouldn't recommend it.

You havr to ask the Coop board if they will allow it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the time to reply.  This a disappointing, but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to make an inverted T shape with the ducts. This will make the fan suck from both rooms, but now the suction will be split between them. If split equally it may be half the suction in each room. If one side is blocked you may end up with one side having more suction than the other. You can try to use a register with a close-able grill for this.

Someone mentioned smells going between rooms. Worse, if the new room is a bathroom, it will make unsanitary air move to the kitchen. You can reduce this by adding a divider inside the ductwork, but you would need some way of gluing/sealing the divider. It would look like this:

```
    |FFF|
    |   |
   _| | |_
-> |__|__| <-
```

The taller you make the divider, the less the smell will go across. However this will also interfere with airflow and make the suction less.

However, since you haven't bought it yet, it's probably better to just give up on this apartment and keep shopping.